# Is it possible to run Mathematica on an HPC cluster with Torque?

Tags: installation, high-performance-clusters

I'm installing Wolfram gridMathematica for use in a high-performance computing (HPC) cluster which uses TORQUE Resource Manager for [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System). Mathematica seems to support PBS pro; has anyone had success using gridMathematica with OpenPBS or TORQUE?

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake, can you tell s bit about what you want to do with all of this, what problem you want to solve or model or calculate?

Comment: Very good question. I do wonder why they chose to support PBS Pro rather than Torque. If I had to choose only one of these, I would think Torque support would have been more widely applicable.